# template breaks before loading properly

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, metronic

My website is developed in `PHP` `Laravel 5.5` framework with `Metronic` templates for CSS.

All the web pages break before loading correctly.

Its visible for 1 sec and in next 2-3 seconds the page loads properly with proper CSS and JS.

I have checked for any JS breaks, but there are none.
Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please provide more insight? It's a bit vague

Comment: How can we help without seeing a code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use Page Loading.

**Why is this happening?**

Metronic loads alot of css/js files, until they fully rendered it may take time and thats why you see your page is broken for a second and after the 2. / 3. seconds its fully loaded.

- If its happening every time you open a page, it means you don't use caching on your site.
- It always a good practice to use page loading, because we don't know how long will it take to load on clients browser.

You can use below code to show/hide page loading:

```
App.startPageLoading({animate: true});
App.stopPageLoading();
```

For more example you can check :

- [ui-block](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/ui_page_progress_style_1.html)
- [ui-page-progress-style](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/ui_blockui.html)